# Match only part of regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

I need to filter list of names using `regex`.

I have stored data in this format

```json
[
 {
  "firstName": "Jhon",
  "lastName": "Doe",
 },
 ...
]
```

User can enter either full name, first name or last name. But I need to match them all. My mongo query goes like this (I used `Loopback 4` to build this query but idea is obvious)

```js
        {
          or: [{firstName: new RegExp(searchKey, 'i')}, {lastName: new RegExp(searchKey, 'i')}],
        };
```

But this does not match when user enters *jhon doe* but it works when first name or last name only entered.

My question is, is there a way to match part of the string against regex?

expected to return successful match for all "jhon", "doe", "jhon doe" and "jhondoe"

Comment: `searchKey.split(/\s/g).join('|')` ..?

Comment: Yes, this is a solution. But assume user enters "jhondoe"??

Comment: Tha wouldn't be a valid part of the user's name by any criteria, hence that should fail. You could add `'|'+ searchKey` to the end of the string to include the original search key too, but I'd drop that alternative.

Comment: Agree if it is usernames. but these are names of users and requirement is to find matching names. I need to know can this be implemented with some kind of regexp statemen. BTW, your above comment worked for now

Comment: Have you considered a [Text Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#overview)?

Comment: @HanielBaez indexes are a different story

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible to write a generic regex that can do this, I made a brute force algorithm to build the regex.

```js
let text = `[
    {
     "firstName": "Jhon",
     "lastName": "Doe",
    },
    ...
   ]`;

// Brute force
let key = "jhondoe";
let keyArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
    let a = key.slice(0, i);
    let b = key.slice(i);
    a && keyArr.push(a);
    b && keyArr.push(b);
}
let keySearch = keyArr.join("|");
console.error(keySearch);
let regex = new RegExp(`"(?:first|last)Name": "(${keySearch})"`, `gim`);
let matches = text.match(regex);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: WOW!!!!.. this is brut-al. you may get unexpected results as it compares per letter also.. But I understood that my question deserves this answer. I'm not sure whether I should accept this answer or not, but it is correct

Comment: Maybe modify to accept the whole word, or if it is a substring, you have to match the name and lastname at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Now I made a complete code, which considers several things. Unfortunately, if someone has a name jhon doe and someone else has a name jhond oe this code will accept it.

The main idea is to check if the key is the first name OR the last name. Otherwise, if it contains spaces, everything before the first space is firstName, and everything after is lastName. Otherwise, using brute force, it tests all combinations of firstName and lastName, the left substring is fisrtName the right substring is lastName.

```js
let text = `[
    {
     "firstName": "Jhon",
     "lastName": "Doe",
    },
    ...
   ]`;

const nameValidator = (key, text) => {
  // Attempts to check whether the entire key received is a first or last name.
  let regexKey = new RegExp(`"(?:first|last)Name": "${key}"`, `gim`);
  if (regexKey.test(text)) {
    return true;
  } else if (key.includes(" ")) {
    // if the key has spaces, we already know the first and lastName
    // if the key has more than one space, everything after the first space goes to lastName
    let [_, a, b] = /^(\w+) (.*)$/.exec(key);
    let regexFirstLastName = new RegExp(`"firstName": "${a}",(\\s|\\t|\\n)*"lastName": "${b}",`, `gim`);
    if (regexFirstLastName.test(text)) {
      return true;
    }
  } else {
    // Search by brute force for the division between first and last name
    for (let i = 1; i < key.length; i++) {
      let a = key.slice(0, i);
      let b = key.slice(i);
      console.log(`Trying name="${a}" and lastname="${b}"`);
      let regexFirstLastName = new RegExp(`"firstName": "${a}",(\\s|\\t|\\n)*"lastName": "${b}",`, `gim`);
      if (regexFirstLastName.test(text)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

const keys = ["jhon", "doe", "jhon doe", "jhondoe", "auehuaheuahe"];

for (key of keys) {
  console.log(key, nameValidator(key, text));
  console.log("=======================\n");
}
```